# How to know if a segment is completely included between two lines?

Tags: geometry

I have three segments (not necessarily parralel):

- blue $((ax1, ay1), (ax2, ay2))$
- green$((bx1, by1), (bx2, by2))$
- red $((cx1, cy1), (cx2, cy2))$

and a $margin$ value which is the width of the sky blue band in the sketch bellow (with infinite length and always centered to the blue segment).

[image]

Is there a way to know if a segment is completely in the sky blue band knowing the coordinates of each segment and the value of the margin ?

Comment: Let $r$ be the half-width of the margin.  Then $b$ is in the margin iff the [distance between each endpoint of $b$ and the line $r(t) = a_1 + (a_2-a_1)t$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Vector_formulation) is $\lt r$ (or $\le r$ depending on whether you want to include the boundary of the margin).

Answer (score 1):

1. From $[(cx_1, cy_1), (cx_2, cy_2)]$ find $(M_x, M_y)$ of M, the midpoint of c.
2. From $[(ax_1, ay_1), (ax_2, ay_2)]$, find L, the equation of a. Let say it is $L: Ax + By + C = o$.
3. From the above, find d, the distance of M of from L. d is given by $|\dfrac {A(M_x) + B(M_y) + C}{\sqrt {A^2 + B^2}}|$.
4. Compare d with half of the margin value.
5. If a and c are not parallel (i.e. slope of a is not the same as c), extra checking is necessary by testing $d_1$ and $d_2$; where $d_1$ is found by the same formula with $(M_x)$ and $(M_y)$ replaced by $cx_1$ and $cx_2$ respectively. $d_2$ is similarly defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The sky blue margin is *convex*, so the segment is in the interior if and only if its endpoints are.

Comment: What is the simplest way to determine whether an endpoint is in the margin?

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Since the band is convex, to make sure the segment is completely in the band, you only need two endpoints in the band. (It is applicable for all convex domains)

Answer (score 0):

If both endpoints are within the band, the segment is completely within the band.

The band is $2 h$ wide, and centered on a line passing through points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$.

(Note that I am using $(x_1,y_1)$ instead of $(ax1, ay1)$, and $(x_2, y_2)$ instead of $(ax2, ay2)$, and $h = {margin}/2$, because I find it clearer this way.)

Therefore, point $(x,y)$ is within the band if and only if its distance from the line passing through points $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ is at most $h$.

[Point-line distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html) is fortunately easy to calculate:
$$d = \frac{\left\lvert (x_2-x_1)(y_1-y) - (y_2-y_1)(x_1-x)\right\rvert}{\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2}}$$

Thus, if both endpoints of a segment fulfill $2 d \le margin$ (or, $d \le margin/2$, or $d \le h$), the segment is completely within the band.